# Custom block on product view page is not rendered

Tags: configurable-product, layout, magento2, frontend

I have to add a panel into the frontend's product view page. Originally, I will find the full action name of the product page, which is `catalog_product_view` in this case, and add a handler which reference to the panel's block later. However, something really strange is happening, as Magento only look for **configurable products** to add the panel:
[image]

Not with the **simple** products:

[image]

Here's the code for that:

```
$fullActionName = $observer->getEvent()->getFullActionName();
$layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
$option_wrapper = $layout->getBlock('product.info.options.wrapper');
$handler = '';
if ( $fullActionName == 'catalog_product_view') {
    $handler = 'catalog_product_view_handler';
}
if ($handler)  $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle($handler);
```

I'm pretty sure my solution is right. How could this happen?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to add custom block to all product pages by creating custom layout handle in your module `VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`. Is there any reason why it is not suitable in your case and observer should be used instead?

Comment: Well I did implement these code in an observer, which is triggered on the event `layout_load_before`.

Comment: Have you tried to add new `catalog_product_view` handle in your module? It is not clear why you need to manipulate with layout manually in observer when the same result can be achieved using standard framework capabilities.

Comment: I usually look for specific events to add blocks into the page, this is what I learned before. I'm quite new to the framework :)

Comment: By the way, my handler references to the block `product.info.options.wrapper` and add a new block within it. Is this part of the problem?

Comment: It may be a problem if this block is not rendered in on simple product page (not sure about this). Try to use `product.info` instead.

Comment: Didn't worked out unfortunately, guess I have to find a way around. Thank you.